# How can you add a new keyword to clang, a keyword that would be treated as main?

Tags: c++, c, clang

How can a new keyword be added to clang? The new keyword should be a function qualifier. Where would the declaration part go?

Thanks.

Comment: sounds like you need to spelunk into the parsing and lexing sections for clang/LLVM and go from there, I suspect you'd probably get better help from the clang mailing list

Comment: i've edited the IdentifierTabe.cpp, and added the new keyword to TokenKinds.def as far as from parsing and lexing I can't find the behavior of main from C as i don't know where it's defined.

Comment: [One of the disadvantages of Clang versus Elsa](http://clang.llvm.org/comparison.html#elsa) is that Elsa uses a nice parser completely based on grammar rules. I've always wondered why Clang developers didn't choose to write their parser in the same way...

Comment: @peoro, Elsa is very slow, whereas Clang with its horrible, handrwitten recursive descent parser is faster then GCC.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to add it to include/clang/Basic/TokenKinds.def, and then add a new case to ParseDeclarationSpecifiers(...).

Probably an easier option would be to define a new attribute, and then use

`#define your_new_qualifier __attribute__((your_new_attribute))`

Otherwise you'd have to add this qualifier support to the AST, which could be error-prone, whereas attributes are propagated automatically across various declarations of the same function.

Comment: Where do i define its behaviour ? is there any documentation on where is implemented the behaviour, beside the code?

Comment: I have not seen any documentation on this particular aspect of Clang, but it's quite easy to just copy and paste similar things - in your case it would be an implementation of 'inline', for example (this one is in AST), or the address space attribute for the second option.

Comment: In which file we need to do #define your_new_qualifier __attribute__((your_new_attribute)) and where to add "your_new_attribute"