# frontend to LLVM-based compiler

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, llvm, clang, llvm-gcc

I am trying to develop a compiler based on the LLVM infrastructure. My language has a C like syntax and so I would like to leverage existing C compilers. Right now I am focusing on the frontend (lexical analysis, parsing), but I am confused as to which frontend would be the best approach. Clang, llvm-gcc or traditional flex/bison tools?

I am specially interested in the simplest solution which would allow me to generate LLVM IR code for later stages of my compiler.

Comment: If you're doing your own parsing and semantic analysis, generating LLVM IR would be easy enough. You could have reused an existing frontend, like Clang, if you had to borrow a large part of C syntax. Otherwise it does not worth it, generating IR is trivial once you've got a valid AST.

Comment: Thanks. What should I use for generating IR from the AST?

Comment: use just straightforward substitution rules - see the LLVM Kaleidoscope example.

Comment: Look at this tutorial: http://gnuu.org/2009/09/18/writing-your-own-toy-compiler/ it shows how use bison+flex to create an AST and then export it to LLVM I.R.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. My language borrows a lot from C, so I thought it is better to hack existing compiler frontends (clang). Right now I am interested to simply add my own keywords to the lexer for a start, but I get a bit scared by the size of codes in the lex library. Can anyone point me to which files I should modify to make this happen. I am reading the documentation but it takes quite some time to get used to all the classes..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736738/how-can-you-add-a-new-keyword-to-clang-a-keyword-that-would-be-treated-as-main

Answer (score 2):

If you want to code everything by hand, then I recommand you the LLVM tutorial Kaleidoscope:

- http://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/

Comment: Is there some source code example? It's easier for me to understand source than text.

Comment: Well the source code is also provided in the tutorial: http://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/LangImpl8.html